# IOS App: Change selling territories after release?

Tags: ios, store, region

is it possible to change the app's selling region for the apple app store on ios **after** release?

I'd like to make the app available for Germany and in the near future for other countries.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can change app's selling region after app is live even you can change it any time